# How to push to a specific array item in the vuex state

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm new to Vue, and more recently Vuex and trying to figure out how to mutate a specific post within the global state using vuex after an action has been committed.

Here is an example of the state.

```
// Array of posts

[
    { 
        id: 1,
        body: "This is an example post",
        comments: [
            { id: 1, body: "This is a comment" }
        ]
    },
    { 
        id: 2,
        body: "This is an example post 2",
        comments: [
            { id: 1, body: "This is a comment 2" }
        ]
    },
    { 
        id: 3,
        body: "This is an example post 3",
        comments: [
            { id: 1, body: "This is a comment 3" }
        ]
    },
]
```

And here is the action I've designed to add a new comment. The comment is being successfully created in the database, but I'm stuck on finding a way to push the comment into the correct part of the state, as I'm trying to mutate a child property.

```js
const actions = {
    async new_post() {
        ...
    },
    async new_comment({ commit }, data) {
    const response = await axios.post(
      'http://localhost:3000/api/posts/' + data.id + '/comments/new', {
        body: data.body
      }
    );
    commit('new_comment', {
      res: response.data, // The object (comment) I want to push into a specific post
      id: data.id, // The id of the post I want to push the comment into
    })
  }
}

const mutations = {
  new_comment: (state, incoming) => {
    state.posts.filter(post => post._id === incoming.id) // Is the post I want to update
    console.log(incoming.res) // The object I want to update the post.comments with.
    } 
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achive this using map.

Try this code.

```
state.posts = state.posts.map(function (post) {
        if (post.id === incoming.id) {
          return incoming
        }
        return item
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing your **"Array of Objects"** to and **"Object of Objects"** and giving every Object a *key* like this:

```
{
  1: {
      .....
     },
  2: {
      .....
     }
....
}
```

then you can add objects to them by calling them by their *key* which should be the same as the *id*.